# Master Slider Start Over When Loop, Not Go In Reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using Master Slider For JQuery and I made the view to fade but when it auto loop it gos back in reverse not starting over from the first slide anybody can help me?

Is there an option for that I looked in the documentation but I did not find anything about that and the knowledge base in their web site is almost empty, any help will be appreciated...

Thanks In Advance

Edit:

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
        slider.setup('masterslider', {
            width: 502,
            height: 332,
            centerControls: false,
            speed: 8,
            autoplay:true,
            hideLayers:true,
            view: 'fade'
        });
        //slider.control('arrows');
        slider.control('bullets', { autohide: false });
```

Comment: Can you post the slider options jquery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, I think you need to add loop option.

```
var slider = new MasterSlider();
    slider.setup('masterslider', {
        width: 502,
        height: 332,
        centerControls: false,
        speed: 8,
        autoplay:true,
        hideLayers:true,
    loop: true,
        view: 'fade'
    });
    //slider.control('arrows');
    slider.control('bullets', { autohide: false });
```